# How to split one column into two columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have small question about SQL Server, please tell me how to solve this issue

Table: `emp`

```
   id    name
  ---------------
   1    abc_rao
   2    nani
   3    hari_babu
   4    kalibabu
   5    ab_tan
```

Based on that table I want output like below

```
   id   firstname   lastname
   1      abc       rao
   2      nani      nothing
   3      hari      babu
   4      kalibabu  nothing
   5      ab        tan
```

and I tried like this:

```
select 
    SUBSTRING(name, 1, CHARINDEX('_', name) - 1) as firstname , 
    SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX('_', name) + 1, LEN(name)) as lastname 
from emp
```

but I'm not getting exactly the expected result.

Instead, I'm getting an error:

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
>   Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Please tell me how to solve this

Issue using query in SQL Server

Comment: If you can alter the design at this point then I suggest that you do so. Save the names into two fields to begin with. This is a better design.

Comment: You absoolutely get the expected result - you just never really put your mind into what you wrote. See, for nani (id 2) there is no _, so the charindex will return NULL, which is not valid input for substring     (so you need a coalesce there to turn that into a  number). And then in your putpu the "nothing" comes exactly from where?

Answer (score 25):

try this:

```
select 
    case when CHARINDEX('_',name)>0 
         then SUBSTRING(name,1,CHARINDEX('_',name)-1) 
         else name end firstname, 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_',name)>0 
         THEN SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX('_',name)+1,len(name))  
         ELSE NULL END as lastname
from emp
```

you can use CASE command to control is last name available.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/32033)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
declare @t table (id int, name  varchar(50))

insert into @t (id,name) values( 1    ,'abc_rao')
insert into @t (id,name) values( 2    ,'nani')
insert into @t (id,name) values( 3    ,'hari_babu')
insert into @t (id,name) values( 4    ,'kalibabu')
insert into @t (id,name) values( 5    ,'ab_tan')

select 
    case when CHARINDEX('_',name)>0 
         then SUBSTRING(name,1,CHARINDEX('_',name)-1) 
         else name end firstname, 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_',name)>0 
         THEN SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX('_',name)+1,len(name))  
         ELSE NULL END as lastname
from @t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/32033/0)**:

```
| FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME |
|-----------|----------|
|       abc |      rao |
|      nani |   (null) |
|      hari |     babu |
|  kalibabu |   (null) |
|        ab |      tan |
```

UPDATED: sqlfiddle added

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @table table(name varchar(300))
insert into @table values('Raj Parmar')
insert into @table values('Ronak mer')
insert into @table values('Mayuri nikunj trivedi')

Select 
DISTINCT name,
   SUBSTRING(name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', name) - 1) as FirstName,
   RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(name,SUBSTRING(name , 1, CHARINDEX(' ', name) - 1),''),REVERSE( LEFT( REVERSE(name), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(name))-1 ) ),'')))as MiddleName,
   REVERSE( LEFT( REVERSE(name), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(name))-1 ) ) as LastName
From @table

name                    FirstName      MiddleName          LastName
Mayuri nikunj trivedi    Mayuri        nikunj               trivedi
Raj Parmar               Raj                                Parmar
Ronak mer               Ronak                               mer
```

Answer (score 3):

You miss the case where there's no underscore in the string, which causes the error. Instead, try:

```
select
    case CHARINDEX('_', name) when 0 then name
        else SUBSTRING(name, 1, CHARINDEX('_', name) - 1) end firstName,

    case CHARINDEX('_', name) when 0 then name
        else SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX('_', name) + 1, LEN(name)) end lastname 
from emp
```

I assume in the case of a single word, you want to show them as both the first name and last name. You can change that value to whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @tbl table(name varchar(20))

insert into @tbl values ('Abdul$Rahim')

insert into @tbl values('Tariq$Jameel')

select

PARSENAME(replace(name,'$','.'),2) as firstname,
PARSENAME(replace(name,'$','.'),1) as lastname

from @tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

Is easier using Using Split_string function and a dynamic pivot

> declare @TestPorformance as table
> (
> DirtyId     int identity
> ,[Text]     varchar(max)
> )
>
> insert into @TestPorformance([Text])values('Pedro guevera,58,jalisco')
> insert into @TestPorformance([Text])values('Juan Sandoval,80,colima')
> insert into @TestPorformance([Text])values('Karla hinojosa,71,jalisco')
> insert into @TestPorformance([Text])values('Luis gonzalez,15,jalisco')
>
> select
> [2] AS [Id]
> ,[1] AS [Name]
> ,[3] AS [State]
> from
> (select
> TP.DirtyId
> ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TP.DirtyId) - ((TP.DirtyId -1) * 3) AS Row_Csc_Id
> ,txt.Value
> from
> @TestPorformance  TP
> cross apply
> string_split(tp.[Text],',') AS Txt) X
> pivot
> (
> min([value]) for Row_Csc_Id in( [1],[2],[3])
> )p