# Create new column by each value separated by ";" SQL Server SUBSTRING

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have  this **'Tests'** column with n Rows

```
1 Test0;Test1;Test2
2 Test3;Test5;Test8
...
...
```

I need to separate each value by semicolon and create 1 column for each index.

This should be the result:

```
Column New1: 
Test0
Test3
Column New2:
Test1
Test5
Column New3:
Test2
Test8
```

Comment: What is the SQL Server version and does `Tests` column always have text with 3 parts? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably close enough to what you want:

```
select t.*, s.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then s.value end) as test_1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then s.value end) as test_2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then s.value end) as test_3             
      from (select s.value,
                   row_number() over (order by charindex(';' + s.value + ';', ';' + t.tests + ';')) as seqnum
            from string_split(t.tests, ';') s
           ) s
     ) s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b96f31eaa02e23bfbb716aa192a33e8b) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  This approach will not work if there are duplicates in the column.

Comment: Im having the trouble of duplicates in the column.. 
They are not properly order...

Answer (score 0):

Solved here [How to split one column into two columns in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652225/how-to-split-one-column-into-two-columns-in-sql-server)

(Note: this approach is made to split one column into two columns)

```
declare @t table (id int, name  varchar(50))

select 
    case when CHARINDEX(';', Column)>0 
         then SUBSTRING(Column, 1, CHARINDEX(';', Column)-1) 
         else Column end Column1, 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(';', Column)>0 
         THEN SUBSTRING(Column, CHARINDEX(';',Column)+1,len(Column))  
         ELSE NULL END as Column2
from @t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select SUBSTRING(Tests,1,CHARINDEX(';', Tests)-1) as New1,
SUBSTRING(Tests,CHARINDEX(';', Tests)+1,CHARINDEX(';', Tests,CHARINDEX(';', Tests)-1)-1) as New2,
SUBSTRING(Tests,CHARINDEX(';', Tests,CHARINDEX(';', Tests)+1)+1,len(Tests)) as New3
```